# All (or Mostly) Encompassing Mobile Device Emulator

Tags: android-emulator, ios-simulator

My Google black belt has fallen off and I'm unable to find a single mobile device emulator that can be installed on Windows 7. I would be satisfied if it only supported iPhone and Android emulation.

Do any such emulators exist?

EDIT:

To clarify, I'm not asking if I can develop for the iPhone (or any other devices for that matter) on a Windows 7 machine. I'm asking if an emulator exists that would allow me to see a close approximation of how a site would be rendered on an iPhone, Android, or some other mobile device.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Android SDK comes with an emulator, but to do iphone development, you will need a Mac. Bottom line.

Comment: I'm not sure we're on the same page. I'm not talking about iPhone development, I'm talking about mobile phone emulation. For example, I'd like to see how a mobile site that I developed looks on both Androi and iPhone by using an emulator on my Windows 7 machine. I'll edit my post to clarify.

Comment: Yea, there is still no IPhone emulator. You can install the android SDK and get that simulator to load your web page.

Answer (score 0):

Not exactly an emulator, but you can use a plugin for Firefox/Chrome called User Agent switcher, which allows you to easily render mobile sites using a standard browser.

- [User Agent Switcher for Firefox](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/user-agent-switcher/)
- [User Agent Switcher for Chrome](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/djflhoibgkdhkhhcedjiklpkjnoahfmg)

You'll also need the actual user agents to switch to, I use the ones found on TechPatterns (below), but you can find many more lists just by searching.

- [User Agent Lists](http://techpatterns.com/forums/about304.html)